# How to Center Menu on Responsive Checkbox Hamburger Menu

Tags: html, css, checkbox, responsive-design, hamburger-menu

I've successfully made an hamburger menu that only appears after a certain width, but the problem is that I would like the nav links to be centered, to occupy the whole page (here it stops once the links in the menu are done) and to have a different background color.
Here's an example how the layout I'd like: [image: layout example] 
I've used CSSS and HTML only and would like to stick to these if possible.

Here's the code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylenav.css">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <link href="css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <link rel='icon' href='FAVICON.jpg' type='image/x-icon'/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <title>AURORA CATERA 2020</title>
    </head>

    <body>

        <header class="header">
            <a href="index.html"><img src="img/AURORA-YLOW-FIN copy.png" class="logo"></a>
            <input class="menu-btn" type="checkbox" id="menu-btn" />
            <label class="menu-icon" for="menu-btn"><span class="nav-icon"></span></label>
            <ul class="menu">
                <li><a href="#dont">ALL</a></li>
                <li><a href="#forget">STUFF</a></li>
                <li><a href="#subscribe">ABOUT</a></li>
                <li><a href="#comment">CONTACT</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://www.instagram.com/auroracatera" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></li></i></a>
            </ul>


        </header>


        </body>
        </html>
```

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:900&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cormorant+Garamond:300&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:500&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Work+Sans:100,200,300,400,600&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rajdhani:400&display=swap');


body{
    margin:0;
    background-color:#000;
}

a{
    color:#F8E315;
    font-family: Rajdhani, sans-serif;
}

.header{
    background-color:rgb(153, 57, 57);
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    z-index:3;
}

.header ul{
    margin:0;
    padding: 20px 30px 0 0;
    list-style:none;
    overflow:hidden;
    background-color:rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

.header ul a{
    display:block;
    padding:20px;
    text-decoration:none;
}

.header ul a:hover{
   color:#c7c7c7; 
}

.header .logo{
    float:left;
    display:block;
    height: 62px;
    padding: 30px 0 0 40px;

}

.header .menu{
    clear:both;
    max-height:0;
    transition:max-height .2s ease-out;
}

.header .menu-icon{
    padding: 58px 20px;
    position:relative;
    float:right;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.header .menu-icon .nav-icon{
    background:#F8E315;
    display:block;
    height:2px;
    width:30px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    position:relative;
    transition:background;
}

.header .menu-icon .nav-icon:before{
    background: #F8E315;
    content:"";
    display:block;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    border-radius: 2px;
    position:absolute;
    top:10px;  

}

.header .menu-icon .nav-icon:after{
    background:#F8E315;
    content:"";
    display:block;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    border-radius: 2px;
    position:absolute;
    top:-10px;  

}

.header .menu-btn{
    display:none;
}

.header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu{
    max-height:240px;

}

.header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon .nav-icon{
    background:transparent;
}
.header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon .nav-icon:before{
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    top:0;
}
.header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon .nav-icon:after{
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    top:0;
}

@media (min-width:48em){

    .header li{
        float:left;
    }

    .header .menu{
        clear:none;
        float:right;
        max-height:none;
    }

    .header .menu-icon{
        display:none;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

just add text-align:center to your ul tag

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:900&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cormorant+Garamond:300&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:500&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Work+Sans:100,200,300,400,600&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rajdhani:400&display=swap');

ul{
text-align:center;
}
body{
    margin:0;
    background-color:#000;
}

a{
    color:#F8E315;
    font-family: Rajdhani, sans-serif;
}

.header{
    background-color:rgb(153, 57, 57);
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    z-index:3;
}

.header ul{
    margin:0;
    padding: 20px 30px 0 0;
    list-style:none;
    overflow:hidden;
    background-color:rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

.header ul a{
    display:block;
    padding:20px;
    text-decoration:none;
}

.header ul a:hover{
   color:#c7c7c7; 
}

.header .logo{
    float:left;
    display:block;
    height: 62px;
    padding: 30px 0 0 40px;

}

.header .menu{
    clear:both;
    max-height:0;
    transition:max-height .2s ease-out;
}

.header .menu-icon{
    padding: 58px 20px;
    position:relative;
    float:right;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.header .menu-icon .nav-icon{
    background:#F8E315;
    display:block;
    height:2px;
    width:30px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    position:relative;
    transition:background;
}

.header .menu-icon .nav-icon:before{
    background: #F8E315;
    content:"";
    display:block;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    border-radius: 2px;
    position:absolute;
    top:10px;  

}

.header .menu-icon .nav-icon:after{
    background:#F8E315;
    content:"";
    display:block;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    border-radius: 2px;
    position:absolute;
    top:-10px;  

}

.header .menu-btn{
    display:none;
}

.header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu{
    max-height:240px;

}

.header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon .nav-icon{
    background:transparent;
}
.header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon .nav-icon:before{
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    top:0;
}
.header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon .nav-icon:after{
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    top:0;
}

@media (min-width:48em){

    .header li{
        float:left;
    }

    .header .menu{
        clear:none;
        float:right;
        max-height:none;
    }

    .header .menu-icon{
        display:none;
    }

}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylenav.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/menu.css">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <link href="css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <link rel='icon' href='FAVICON.jpg' type='image/x-icon'/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <title>AURORA CATERA 2020</title>
    </head>

    <body>

        <header class="header">
            <a href="index.html"><img src="img/AURORA-YLOW-FIN copy.png" class="logo"></a>
            <input class="menu-btn" type="checkbox" id="menu-btn" />
            <label class="menu-icon" for="menu-btn"><span class="nav-icon"></span></label>
            <ul class="menu">
                <li><a href="#dont">ALL</a></li>
                <li><a href="#forget">STUFF</a></li>
                <li><a href="#subscribe">ABOUT</a></li>
                <li><a href="#comment">CONTACT</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://www.instagram.com/auroracatera" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
            </ul>


        </header>


        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: thanks, I had tried before but probably added it to the wrong tag. The most puzzling part to me is how to have a different color in the background that fits the whole page once I click on the hamburger menu